# Best method to find duplicate of a particular file or a particular set of files

Tags: linux, bash

I have been using `fdupes` to find duplicate files in my filesystem, however, I often find myself wanting to, either, find duplicates of *a particular file* or find duplicates of the files in a particular directory.

To elaborate, if I call

```
fdupes dir1 dir2
```

The result will be all duplicate files found in the collected set of files in `dir1` and `dir2`.  However, I would really like to be able to do something like

```
fdupes-alternative file dir
```

to find duplicates of `file` in `dir` without being bothered with duplicate files in `dir`.  Or even being able to something like

```
fdupes-alternative dir1 dir2
```

and to check of any of the files in `dir1` are duplicated in `dir2`, again, ignoring the duplicates if they are either all in `dir1` or `dir2`.

Are there any tools which does this sort of thing, or any easy way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Your question is a bit terse that it could literally be taken in  different ways. For example do you consider links duplicates? Or just files with same hashes? In  the case of hard-links, if you wish to delete one(an obvious follow-up action) what would be your take?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow [...].*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter groups for the content of interest.

Assuming `fdupes` output format of line per file plus blank line to separate groups, if you are interested in a file, filter on groups that contain the filename as a line. For example with awk:

```
fdupes file dir |\
awk -v F=file '
    BEGIN { FS="\n"; RS="\n\n" }
    {
        for (i=NF; i; i--)
            if ($i==F) {
                printf("%s%s", x++?RS:"", $0)
                break
            }
    }
'
```

If you are interested in a directory, filter on groups that contain lines that start with that directory. For example, again with 'awk':

```
fdupes dir1 dir2 |\
awk -v D=dir1/ '
    BEGIN { FS="\n"; RS="\n\n" }
    {
        for (i=NF; i; i--)
            if (index($i,D)==1) {
                printf("%s%s, x++?RS:"", $0
                break
            }
    }
```